# How was this heat semigroup estimate made in a paper on reaction–diffusion systems?

Tags: integration, parabolic-pde, semigroups-of-operators

In [Yamauchi - Blow-up results for a reaction–diffusion system](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/methods-and-applications-of-analysis/volume-13/issue-4/Blow-up-Results-for-a-Reaction-Diffusion-System/maa/1202219967.full), in the proof of **Lemma 3.3**, there is the passage

$$S(t-s)|x|^{\sigma/1-k} \geq C_1(t-s)^{\sigma/2(1-k)}.$$
Here $S(t)$ denotes the heat kernel. I tried to do the calculations to check this inequality but I couldn't, I tried to open the semigroup definition, using $t$ in place of $t-s$ to see better

\begin{align}
S(t)|x|^{\sigma/1-k} = (4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\lvert x-y\rvert^2/4t}\lvert y\rvert^{\sigma/1-k}dy.
\end{align}
I made the change of variable
$z=(x-y)/2t^{1/2}$, then $dz = t^{-n/2}dy $ and $y = x - 2t^{1/2}z$, so
\begin{align}
S(t)\lvert x\rvert^{\sigma/1-k} &= (4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\lvert x-y\rvert^2/4t}\lvert y\rvert^{\sigma/1-k}dy\\
& = (4\pi)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\lvert z\rvert^2}\lvert x - 2t^{1/2}z\rvert^{\sigma/1-k}dz\\
&= (4\pi)^{-n/2}t^{\sigma/2(1-k)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\lvert z\rvert^2}\lvert x/t^{1/2} - 2z\rvert^{\sigma/1-k}dz.
\end{align}
I only got so far, what I'm not sure is how to limit this last integral by $C_1$. I don't know if he just assumed that the integral is positive, since the inner function is positive, or if it's some invariance property of this integral by translation $x$. Does anyone know how this is done?

Comment: One suggestion is to study the t-derivative integral itself in the very last equality because both for t->0 and t->infinity, the integral is away from zero.

Comment: Abbreviate $r=x/t^{1/2}$. For $|r| \leq 3$ (say), there is a positive lower bound because the integral is a continuous function of $r$ which attains a minimum on the closed ball of radius $3$ and this minimum has to be positive. If $|r|>3$ on the other hand, the integral can be lower bounded by an integral over $B_1(0)$ and there the second factor in the integrand is always bigger or equal to a positive constant, which gives another positive lower bound in this case. Combining the two cases you get a uniform lower bound.

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable comments, I was having a hard time seeing this, but now it's clearer.